# French first day of week

Tags: .net, date, datetime

I’m looking from today’s date to get the first day of the week but I have a problem. If my date of the day is a Sunday, he defines me as the first day of the week on the following Monday and not the previous Monday. In French the week begins on Monday

```
startWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)_myCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: You can always subtract 7 to the first day of the week if the current day is a Sunday.

Comment: I want something that doesn’t force me to test to know if it’s Sunday or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following alternatives, regardless of the date, as it will give you the first day of the week as a function of the `DateTime` object you assign to `dateBeginWeek`.

```
public static void Main() 
{
    CultureInfo _myCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    var firstDay = _myCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek; // should be 'Monday'
    Console.WriteLine("The current culture is {0} and FDoW is {1}!", _myCulture.Name, firstDay.ToString());

    DateTime dateBeginWeek = DateTime.Today; // or another Datetime e.g., new DateTime(2020, 4, 09);
    while (dateBeginWeek.DayOfWeek != _myCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
        dateBeginWeek = dateBeginWeek.AddDays(-1);

    Console.WriteLine("First day of current week: {0}", dateBeginWeek);
}
```

or

```
    DateTime dateBeginWeek = DateTime.Today;
    var diffInDays = (int) dateBeginWeek.DayOfWeek - (int) _myCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

    if(diffInDays < 0){ 
        diffInDays += 7;
    }

    dateBeginWeek = dateBeginWeek.AddDays(-diffInDays);
    Console.WriteLine("First day of current week: {0}", dateBeginWeek);
```